Draw parallel line in WinForms
I need to draw kind of parallel line based on the original one like this.

I use this code
 const int shift = 10;
 PointF[] clonedPoints = new PointF[polygon.Count];
 float dx = polygon[1].X - polygon[0].X;
 float dy = polygon[1].Y - polygon[0].Y;

 for (int i = 0; i < polygon.Count; i++)
 {
     var k = (float)Math.Atan2(dx / 100, dy / 100);
     float x = polygon[i].X + k + shift;  
     float y = polygon[i].Y + k + shift;
     clonedPoints[i] = new PointF(x, y);
 }

And I get lines like this.

The blue is the cloned one.
So I tried to play with some koefficient k and shift but it does not help to get "parallel" points to draw them.

What exactly is your available input? Because at first sight this looks just like an issue of translation. But I guess there's more to it?

@Fildor I just use a mouse to click in some places of the pictureBox. In case above I have clicked 3 times.

Ok, 3 clicks => 3 Points. I guess those make two adjacent lines ... now what? Please: We don't know anything about your task outside what you tell us in the questtion. To me, the result is kind of expected and it seems to be more of a math problem?

^^ You are in a cartesian coordinate system. (which in this case is upside-down) So adding a fixed value to both dimensions will translate each point 45 degrees down and right. Which is what we see. If you need an angular component, you will have to compute it for each dimension.

@Fildor I see, please help me to get it working with angular component.

I am really not a Maths-Guy, but I am wondering if it's a rather simple mistake: k is probably supposed to be a factor, not a summand? I.e. it needs to be something like float x = k * polygon[i].X +shift ; or something similar? Probably also needs adjusttment between x and y like "1-k" ...

@Fildor Yep, I am afraid we need kind of maths-boss to help.

I think that you need to calculate a parallel line to each edge of the original polygon and then calculate the intersections of successive lines to get the new edges. You can't just move all vertices in one direction.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes I assumed that direction is supposed to be determined by k. It just doesn't seem to be used correctly. And intersection computation is missing, yes.

This can be a quite complex problem if you want to make it work reliably for arbitrary shapes. If your offset distance is large enough your lines may disappear completely. So for arbitrary shapes it might be easier to rasterize your lines, create a distance field, and convert back to lines with marching squares. For a simple case like the example it should be sufficient to offset each line and check for intersection, like previous commenters suggest.

The existing code has several flaws. E.g., k is calculated for only one line segment and it is a scalar (a number). But we need a vector having an x- and a y-component. Shifting both x and y by k + shift will shift everything in a 45 degrees angle, no matter the orientation of the line. Also k is an angle. Adding an angle is nonsensical.

Let us begin by calculating a parallel line segment for each edge of the original polygon. We assume the declaration private readonly List<PointF> polygon = [];. Only execute the following code if polygon.Count > 1:
// Create shifted segments
const float distance = 10;

// Create the segments as an array of point tuples.
// We have one segment less than there are vertices.
var segments = new (PointF p1, PointF p2)[polygon.Count - 1];

for (int i = 1; i < polygon.Count; i++) {
    // An edge of the polygon
    PointF p1 = polygon[i - 1];
    PointF p2 = polygon[i];

    // Calculate n as the unit vector (vector having a length of 1) from p1 to p2
    var n = Vector2.Normalize(p2.ToVector2() - p1.ToVector2());

    // The unit vector rotated by 90 degrees is (-n.Y, n.X).
    // The rotated unit vector times distance is our shift vector (as SizeF).
    var shift = new SizeF(-n.Y, n.X) * distance;
    // Get the shifted segment
    segments[i - 1] = (p1 + shift, p2 + shift);
}

The intermediate result looks like this:

As you can see, we have now disconnected line segments. We will have to calculate the intersections of adjacent segments to get them connected.
I am using the intersection calculation from this question: Intersection point of 2 lines defined by 2 points each
// Connect adjacent segments by calculating their intersection
// and use the intersection as their new endpoints.

// a = pt 1 on line 1,  b = pt 2 on line 1
var (a, b) = segments[0];

// Factors for segment 1
float a1 = b.Y - a.Y;
float b1 = a.X - b.X;
float c1 = a1 * a.X + b1 * a.Y;

for (int i = 1; i < segments.Length; i++) {
    // c = pt 1 on line 2,  d = pt 2 on line 2
    var (c, d) = segments[i];

    // Factors for segment 2
    float a2 = d.Y - c.Y;
    float b2 = c.X - d.X;
    float c2 = a2 * c.X + b2 * c.Y;

    float determinant = a1 * b2 - a2 * b1;

    if (MathF.Abs(determinant) > 1e-3) { // Otherwise lines are parallel
        float x = (b2 * c1 - b1 * c2) / determinant;
        float y = (a1 * c2 - a2 * c1) / determinant;
        var intersection = new PointF(x, y);
        segments[i - 1].p2 = intersection;
        segments[i].p1 = intersection;
    }

    (a1, b1, c1) = (a2, b2, c2);
}

We could take that as the final result, but probably you want to have a point array for the parallel polygon:
// Create the new polygon from the segments.
var parallelPolygon = new PointF[segments.Length + 1];
parallelPolygon[0] = segments[0].p1;
for (int i = 0; i < segments.Length; i++) {
    parallelPolygon[i + 1] = segments[i].p2;
}

Final result:

As JonasH pointed out in a comment: "If your offset distance is large enough your lines may disappear completely". This solution simply ignores this problem as well as extremely sharp angles leading to vertices being at great distances.

I also ensure that line segments don't have a length of 0 when adding them, otherwise this will blow up our calculations:
private void Form_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (polygon is [.., var p] &&
        MathF.Abs(p.X - e.X) < 1 && MathF.Abs(p.Y - e.Y) < 1) {

        return;
    }
    polygon.Add(new PointF(e.X, e.Y));
    Invalidate();
}

The pattern matching expression polygon is [.., var p] ensures that the polygon has at least one point and assigns the last point to the new variable p.

I am using new C# language features. If you are working with an older .NET Framework version, this video by Nick Chapsas might be helpful for you: Using Latest C# Features in Any Old .NET Version

Wow!  Thank you so much for that deep explanation! It just works!

I just made a little optimization by reusing the calculation of the previous segment factors in the loop.
